# Configure WebStorm/PhpStorm to compile .ts files to .js into "js" folder

Tags: javascript, typescript, phpstorm, webstorm, file-watcher

I use **WebStorm** and I have a project with the following structure:

```
webApp
|--style
|--includes
|--ts
|--js
```

Where "**webApp**" is the project's root.

I'd like to configure a File Watcher that compile the .ts file within the "**ts**" folder into .js files within the "**js**" folder.

In the watcher dialog I set:

```
"$Projectpath$/js/ --sourcemap $FileName$"
```

in the **arguments** field and

```
"$Projectpath$/js/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js:$Projectpath$/js/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js.map"
```

in the **Output paths to refresh** field.

every time I edit a .ts file webstorm shows an error like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/tsc /htdocs/webapp/js/ --sourcemap test.ts

error TS6053: File '/htdocs/webapp/js/.ts' not found.
```

I tried several time to change the macros to point to the external **js** folder but the only way in witch it worked was letting the default option thus the transpiler compile the .ts file that became a 'node' witch contain the .js file and the .map file.

Is there a way to accomplish my purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--out` option will make tsc merge all your files into $FileNameWithoutExtension$.js

If you like to have separate .js file generated, try the following settings:

```
Arguments: --sourcemap --outDir $ProjectFileDir$/js/$FileDirPathFromParent(ts)$ $FileName$
Output paths: $ProjectFileDir$/js/$FileDirPathFromParent(ts)$$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js:$ProjectFileDir$/js/$FileDirPathFromParent(ts)$$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js.map
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this as your arguments value:

```
--out $ProjectFileDir$/js/$FileDirPathFromParent(ts)$$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js $FileName$
```

source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YwBWByAR8ug

Answer (score 1):

The steps below should work both on Web and PHPstorm.

Do you have a **tsconfig.json** file?

If not,  right click on your **Project name** -> **New** -> **tsconfig.json**. 
That file will be created in your project Root folder. Keep it!

If yes, open that file, that should be something like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

and just add the option:

```
"outDir": "JS_FOLDER_PATH_FROM_PROJECT_ROOT"
```

to "compilerOptions" key:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "JS_FOLDER_PATH_FROM_PROJECT_ROOT"
 },
```

As simple as that!

**TIP:** Use the IDE autocompletion to find more options!